# MVC Url Helper generate &amp

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, url

I've this helper:

```
    public static class TestHelper
    {
        public static string Test(this UrlHelper helper)
        {
            var ret = "/Test?par1=1&par2=2";

            return ret;
        }
    }
```

I call it from _Layout.cshtml view

```
<script src="@Url.Test()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the rendered result is:

```
<script src="/Test?par1=1&amp;par2=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I need:

```
<script src="/Test?par1=1&par2=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why add the "&amp" charactes ??
I've tried to use "MvcString" retun but the result is the same

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that to

```
 public static HtmlString Test(this UrlHelper helper)
```

Comment: Your suggestion do not solve the problem. Note that the render is inside a <script>. Infact outside the <script> the render is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Any normal `string` returned from a helper will be html escaped. Return a `MvcHtmlString` to bypass escaping:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Test(this UrlHelper helper)
{
    var ret = "/Test?par1=1&par2=2";
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(ret);        
}
```

Making escaping the default, with an explicit opt-out required greatly increases security for all those places where the developer didn't think of escaping.

Comment: Your suggestion do not solve the problem. Note that the render is inside a <script>. Infact outside the <script> the render is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I sove the problem adding the script tag in the helper function:

```
public static class TestHelper
    {
        public static HtmlString Test(this UrlHelper helper)
        {
            var ret = "/Test?par1=1&par2=2";

            var scriptTag = string.Format("<script src=\"{0}\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", ret);

            return new HtmlString(scriptTag);
        }
    }
```

But I do not undestand why Razor encode the result if it is inside a tag value.

Thank you!